# MY CSS FILE IS MISBEHAVING. IS NOT WORKING WELL ON MY WP SITE

Tags: css

please i have a website, for over weeks now my website got scattered whereas my css file is intact.

please help me, i have reset the .hataccess file, change the theme severally, disable plugins but it still persist. please can someone help me tell me what to do because am getting tired of the site because of the dirtiness.

please i will be happy to welcome any solution.

my site is http://www.examplaza.com

Answer (score 1):

Your [CSS file](http://rockreyad.xtgem.com/tipsad/tipsad_header.css) is Unavaliable from xtgem servers:

> XtGem is coming back in a few days. 
>   We appreciate your support and our apologies for the extended downtime.

Comment: but i changed the theme but it still persists